# Алгоритм увеличения изображения

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

В инете только примеры и алгоритмы без потери качества. А как просто увеличить изображение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Юзайте [`TCanvas.StretchDraw`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TCanvas.StretchDraw). В зависимости от отношения линейных размеров параметра `Rect` к линейным размерам параметра `Graphic` изображение будет отрисовано увеличенным или уменьшенным.

---

"Алгоритма" никакого нет, достаточно выполнить след. соотношение для каждого пиксела приемника:

[image]

где, А - источник, B - приемник, kx, ky - коэффициенты масштабирования по горизонтали и вертикали соответственно.

Comment: Нет. Мне нужен именно алгоритм (или ссылка на него)